# Mailer action error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've written a mailer that wroks prooperly. But i'm having problems with getting the action that invokes the mailer to work.

When a comment is created, within the comment body, for every mention of @someusername, if that user exits, they are sent an email to their email address.

Here is what I have:

```
def create
  @commentable = find_commentable
  @comment = @commentable.comments.build(params[:comment])
  @comment.user = current_user
  if @comment.save
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created comment."
    redirect_to @commentable

      end
    end

  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
```

This is the error I keep getting:

```
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

end

Here is where the error is coming from(inside the mailer):

```
    @user = user
    @url  = 'http://domain.com'
    mail(to: @user.email)
  end
end
```

Comment: You should read the rest of the stack trace, it should point you to the line of code that is calling `.email` on a nil value, which probably means `@user` is nil somewhere.

Comment: K, just did, I should have clarified before, it's from inside the mailer, I guess I'm not properly passing the @user value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`email` is being called on a nil `@user`, and `@user` is going to always be nil.

Looking at this line:

```
unless @user_check = nil
```

Using a single equals is assignment, not an equality comparison.

You'll want to do:

```
unless @user_check == nil
```

or the more idomatic Ruby:

```
unless @user_check.nil?
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much!! :)) It seems like its taking much longer to create comments now, is there anything I can adjust to make it create the comment and then send the email? It seems like its waiting to send the email before redirecting? Or the code I wrote is just intensive and slow??

Comment: @KatieH Yes, by default in Rails, it is going to create and send that email (building the message, connecting to the SMTP server, handshaking, etc.) before going to the next page. You can shove that email creation into a queue to do later with something like `delayed_job`.

Answer (score 1):

Taking `unless @user_check = nil` statement for inspection:--

`=` is assignment and `==` is equality comparison operator. I guess you just missed using `==` because of typo.

Use ruby `.nil?` method instead.

like `unless @user_check.nil?`

Use [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) to send emails.